# unable to add css to checkout index page

Tags: checkout, layout, css

i want to add custom css to only checkout index page but it seems not working

tried below steps

**1: created css file**
/usr/share/nginx/html/app/design/frontend/package_name/theme_name/Magento_Checkout/web/css/checkout.css

**2: update code of checkout_index_index.xml**
app/design/frontend/colora/colora_home2/Magento_Checkout/layout/override/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">


    <head>
        <css src="css/checkout.css"  src_type="url" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  />
    </head>
```

still checkout.css is not getting called on URL : checkout/#payment

please let me know what i am missing

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this in my local test environment. Here are my steps:

Inside your theme create a new layout file:
*app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml*

Inside that file I added this layout update:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="Magento_Checkout::css/custom-checkout.css"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

I then created a CSS file here:

*app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Checkout/web/css/custom-checkout.css*

I added in some test CSS inside:

```
.opc-progress-bar {
    background: #000000;
}
```

Be sure to deploy your static content and flush the cache.

I hope this helps!